# How to hash a geometry point in a 2D plane?

Tags: java, algorithm, hash

Simply say, I have lots of Points in the form of (x, y).

I want to put those points into a hashtable with point being the key.

How should I implement the `hashCode()` method of class `Point`? taking Java as the language

```
class Point {
   public double x;
   public double y;

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
      // How do I implement here?
   }
}
```

Comment: @Cam: I don't think that's a duplicate.  That answer is looking for something that somehow produces identical hashes for geometrically close points.

Comment: Good point. I hereby retract my suggestion to close the question.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth thanks for explaining it for me. Today I already got my 2 or 3 questions closed. Hope this one will survive. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numbers tend to cluster in most coordinate planes; because, we tend to like to use numbers within a comfortable range.  For this reason, the trivial xor combination is not desirable, as all numbers where `x == y` will collide, as will all the numbers where `x + 1 == y` and so on.

To avoid this, I recommend that you reverse the bytes of the y coordinate before you xor it with the x coordinate.  This will combine the area of most variability (the low order bytes) of one input with the area of the least variability (the high order bytes) of the other input.  Such an algorithm will give a more even distribution when considering clusters of numbers (say the values of x between 1 and 1000).

Since hashing algorithms work best when the hash produces a number field without heavy clustering, such a solution will actually make the hash related data structures faster due to less frequent hash collision.

The following is of course, not optimized, and odds are you can probably trim it to suit your needs, but here is the underlying idea:

```
public int hashCode() {

    long bits = Double.doubleToLongBits(y);
    byte[] ybits = new byte[] {
        (byte)((y >> 56) & 0xff),
        (byte)((y >> 48) & 0xff),
        (byte)((y >> 40) & 0xff),
        (byte)((y >> 32) & 0xff),
        (byte)((y >> 24) & 0xff),
        (byte)((y >> 16) & 0xff),
        (byte)((y >> 8) & 0xff),
        (byte)((y >> 0) & 0xff),
    };
    byte[] xbits = new byte[] {
        (byte)((x >> 56) & 0xff),
        (byte)((x >> 48) & 0xff),
        (byte)((x >> 40) & 0xff),
        (byte)((x >> 32) & 0xff),
        (byte)((x >> 24) & 0xff),
        (byte)((x >> 16) & 0xff),
        (byte)((x >> 8) & 0xff),
        (byte)((x >> 0) & 0xff),
    };
    // this combines the bytes of X with the reversed order
    // bytes of Y, and then packs both of those into 4 bytes
    // because we need to return an int (4 bytes).
    byte[] xorbits = new byte[] {
         (xbits[0]^ybits[7])^(xbits[4]^ybits[3]),
         (xbits[1]^ybits[6])^(xbits[5]^ybits[2]),
         (xbits[2]^ybits[5])^(xbits[6]^ybits[1]),
         (xbits[3]^ybits[4])^(xbits[7]^ybits[0]),
    };

    int value = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       value = (value << 8) + (by[i] & 0xff);
    }
    return value;
}
```

Initial optimizations I would suggest would be to cache the hashcode in the object for subsequent lookups, and if profiling suggests it is a problem, perhaps manage the created / destroyed arrays more efficently.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I still have a question on your answer. If I `simply reverse bits of y and then xor x`, will that solve the cases where `x==y`?

Comment: yes, because for the simple case of `x == 10` and `y == 10` the representations in binary might both be something like (fictional example) `0x0000 0000 0000 0101` where y will be byte-order reversed `0x0101 0000 0000 0000`, and the xor will be `0x0101 0000 0000 0101` which conveniently avoids the truism that A ^ A = 0.

Comment: ah, ok, it is byte reverse, i thought it was bit reverse

Comment: You could do bit reverse, but it really doesn't gain you much.  It would be quite a bit more expensive to calculate.  You are already mapping the highly variable parts over likely non-variable parts, and have dodged the `A ^ A == 0` issue, so why waste the extra CPU cycles?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how good the double's hashing is, but you should be able to do:

```
public int hashCode() {
  return x.hashCode() ^ y.hashCode();
}
```

If this gives too many collisions in testing (you do that right?), you can vary it a bit with bit shifting, magic numbers, etc. All kinds of bitwise operations, really.

Is this Java? I'm basing my answer on my experience with C#.

Comment: Yes, this is Java, but I think similar to C#. Could you please explain more on why this will work? I don't know much about how to hash. I get x's hashCode() and y's hashCode(), why a XOR then give a unique hash?

Comment: @JacksonTale: Nothing gives a unique hash.  Although of course, the above method has the disadvantage that (a,b) will hash to the same as (b,a).

Comment: Well, you can't guarantee a unique hash, since the Point has 2^128 possible states, but there are only 2^32 possible hash codes.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth yeah you mean collision is there. but just to maintain a certain level of unique.

Comment: I'm not confident that's a good hash, since similar points will have the same hash (for example, all of the points on the y=x line, etc).

Comment: @KendallFrey Keep in mind that x and y are native types, so you can't call methods on them in Java.  In addition, this hash trivially collides for every instance where x == y.

Comment: @EdwinBuck he said he is using C#. It does not matter much.

Comment: @JacksonTale are you sure?  Java handles primitive types quite differently than C#.  The ideas are the same, but you _cannot_ call a method on a Java primitive, because it is not an Object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use whatever function you want.  It all depends on what typical values your coordinates are, and how good you want the hash function to be.

If e.g. all your points are in the range 1 to 1 million, then you could use something like this (this is C++ code, don't know what language you are using).

```
size_t hashCode = (size_t)x * (size_t)y;
```

Or you can add the values, or multiply the values, or do whatever you want.

```
size_t hashCode = (size_t)(x+y);
```

or

```
size_t hashCode = (size_t)(x*y);
```

or even

```
size_t hashCode = (size_t)(x*y) + (size_t)(x+y);
```

Comment: He is using java, as the tags indicate.  size_t doesn't exist in such a system, which is really a requirement for your solution